Python List to string manipulation. Print each command line argv "--option argument1 argument2" on their own separate lines
I have a working solution, it's just so gross. I often write stuff like this and then just look at it disgusted, but this one is far to gross to leave as is... especially as it's just list to string manipulation. I'm embarrassed. I'm interested in more succinct solutions. Anyone have a cleaner way to put each option parameter followed by its arguments printed on separate lines?
Input: python3 -O myscript.py --dates "2024-04-30" "2024-04-29" "2024-04-28" "2024-04-27" --names "johnson" "woody" "richard" "willy"
-o "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming"
sys.argv[1:] = parameter_set
print("\nGenerating parameter set: ")
parameter_set_string = ""
first_iter = True
for each in parameter_set:
    if each[0] == "-" and first_iter == False:
        print(parameter_set_string)
        parameter_set_string = each
    else: 
        if first_iter:
            parameter_set_string += each
            first_iter = False
        else:
           parameter_set_string += ' "' + each + '" '
print(parameter_set_string)

Output:
Generating parameter set:
--dates "2024-04-30" "2024-04-29" "2024-04-28" "2024-04-27"
--names "johnson" "woody" "richard" "willy" 
-o "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming"

Generating parameter set:
--dates "2024-04-26" "2024-04-25" "2024-04-24"
--names "anaconda" "black mamba" "python" 
-o "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming"


provide a sample input for folks answering, thanks

Why not using argparse that is simpler, cleaner and more readable?

@gold_cy. Sorry, i thought the input was fairly clear from the output. The output is pretty much the input, just on a single line to command line. I'll update.

@Eitan My apologies, this script is building these parameter sets and using another imported script with them as arguments via sys.argv. The other script is not able to be modified.

If I understood your question correctly, the following solution is a bit naive, as it assumes there are no substrings ' -' (space followed by hyphen) within the arguments themselves.
string = 'python3 -O myscript.py --dates "2024-04-30" "2024-04-29" "2024-04-28" "2024-04-27" --names "johnson" "woody" "richard" "willy" -o "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming"'

args = ['-' + arg for arg in string.split(' -')[2:]]
print(*args, sep="\n")

Output:
--dates "2024-04-30" "2024-04-29" "2024-04-28" "2024-04-27"
--names "johnson" "woody" "richard" "willy"
-o "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming"

Also not a huge fan of splitting, removing the delimiter only to be forced to add part of the delimiter back in just to print it. I would say if your arguments don't get more complex than this, this should be fine, otherwise I'd recommend a regex.

I made a mock-up input from your output. I hope it is correct.
parameter_set = [
    "--dates", "2024-04-30", "2024-04-29", "2024-04-28", "2024-04-27",
    "--names", "johnson", "woody", "richard", "willy",
    "-o", "/home/stamos/pickle/pics/name_brainstorming",
]

print("\nGenerating parameter set: ", end="")

for param in parameter_set:
    if param[0] == "-":
        print(f"\n{param}", end="")
    else:
        print(f" \"{param}\"", end="")
print()


This would just print each string on it's own line wouldn't it? We want each "--option 'argument1' 'argument2' 'argument3'" on their own lines. Or how does this work, if you wouldn't mind explaining. The print(f and the end="".

print() uses end='\n' by default which causes the newline. By using the empty string as the end instead we keep printing to the same line. I explicitely print a newline in the if-clause, before printing an option and the following arguments.
The f"text here" string formatting syntax is called "f-strings". It became available with Python 3.6. It allows you to put in variables via curly braces, which is usually much easier to read than combining string parts with + signs.
